# Why I'm running into Heroku error: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' during deployment?

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

Everything looks fine, but I still running into this error once again. The API works in local environment. I think it should be related to heroku configs or so.

**Logs**

```
2022-03-20T14:23:41.391513+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2022-03-20T14:23:41.391513+00:00 app[web.1]:   requireStack: [ '/app/src/router.js', '/app/src/index.js' ]
2022-03-20T14:23:41.391514+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-03-20T14:23:41.515791+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-03-20T14:23:41.587761+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: (a) This isn't happening "during deployment". This is a runtime error. (b) The error message is incomplete. Please [edit] the rest of that error message into your question. (c) Do you believe the module that isn't being found should be found? If so, why? Did you write it? Is it a third-party dependency? Please read [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your time, Chris. I've already solved this issue. I think it happened because Heroku does'nt install development dependencies by default. So I moved those to normal dependencies in the package.json file.